# Grouping dataframe using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
  ordercode             quantity
PMC21-AA1U1FBWBJA           1
PMP23-GR1M1FB3CJ            1
PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA           1
PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7        2
PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA           3
PMC11-AA1L1FJWWJA           3
```

My desired output:

```
  Group    ordercode                quantity
    0       PMC21-AA1U1FBWBJA           1
            PMP23-GR1M1FB3CJ            1
             PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA          1
            PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7        1
    1      PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7         1
            PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA           3
    2      PMC11-AA1L1FJWWJA            3
```

So here my desired result is based on `column['quantity']`. Max value of quantity is `4`.

In `group0 & group1` the total values (1+1+1+1=4)(1+3=4) (i.e keeping the max vale of quantity as 4). In `group2` we can see that no values to add so the group is formed by the left over (here it is 3). In `group0 & group1` we can see that `PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7`'s value splits.

I got little help from the forum and done the following coding:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.apply(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], 1).as_matrix()), 
              columns=['ordercode'])
df['quantity'] = 1
df['group'] = sorted(range(0, len(df)/3, 1) * 4)[0:len(df)]
df.groupby(['group', 'ordercode']).sum()
```

but I am getting error.

```
Type error: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

If I use `int` in

```
df['group'] = sorted(range(0, int(len(df)/3), 1) * 4)[0:len(df)]
```

again I'm getting `typeerror`. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use Python3,
type a double slash `//` to do integer division and convert the range to a list.

```
df['group'] = sorted(list(range(0, len(df) // 3, 1)) * 4)[0:len(df)]
```

For the second attempt, it looks like this.

```
df['group'] = sorted(list(range(0, int(len(df) / 3), 1)) * 4)[0:len(df)]
```

So the full code runs like this.
I copied your example to the clipboard before running.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.apply(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], 1).as_matrix()), 
              columns=['ordercode'])
df['quantity'] = 1
df['group'] = sorted(list(range(0, len(df) // 3, 1)) * 4)[0:len(df)]
df = df.groupby(['group', 'ordercode']).sum()
print(df)
```

The ".as_matrix()" command you used generates a warning, but works.

Comment: Yes I'm using Python 3.I'm getting `Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for *:'range' and 'int'`

Comment: I updated the reply. There was a bracket problem in the first line.

Comment: When I Use list function its giving me a warning. `Future warning: Method .as_Matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values Instead.df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.apply(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], 1).as_matrix()), 
              columns=['ordercode']) ` And I didn't get any result

Comment: I ran your example in jupyter notebooks and get the requested result. I will update the answer to include the running example

Comment: Hey I got the result of `df['group'] = sorted(list(range(0, len(df) // 3, 1)) * 4)[0:len(df)]` but It didn't group `df.groupby(['group', 'ordercode']).sum()`

Comment: Thanks man, You r the best. It works. And One more small help. Can u tell me how to hide the worksheet in excel using Python. Because I saved all dataframe in excel with particular sheetname. Can I hide my sheet mentioning its sheetname ?

Comment: You should post that as a second question with your example code. It depends on how you interact with Excel. So without a detailed example I can only say you can assign the sheet name to a variable.

Comment: Okay. Let me do that

Comment: Hi again, In the above example. If my dataframe is empty how can I skip to perform next .Because here I shows an error that my dataframe is empty and it stops the programming

Comment: And also if my df has very less variables its showing `Valueerror: length of the values does not match length of index`

Comment: Please start a new question rather then extending an answered one. This makes it easier for others to help,too and later, to find the question via the search engine.

Comment: Okay. Let me do that